# Solutions of third order equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm looking for which values of $\rho >0$, the following holds
\begin{align}
- \left[ (b_2 + a \kappa) + (1+\kappa) (b_1 + a \kappa) \right] \rho^2 + \mu \rho - c \kappa \geq 0 ~(1).
\end{align}
where $a$, $b_1$, $b_2$, $c$ and $\mu$ are positive constants and $\kappa > 0$ is a parameter that I can freely set to any positive value.

The discriminant of the quadratic equation is
\begin{align}
\Delta = \mu^2 - 4 c \kappa \left[ (b_2 + a \kappa) + (1+\kappa) (b_1 + a \kappa) \right] ~(2).
\end{align}
To ensure that I can find $\rho > 0$ such that Eq. (1) is satisfied, I need to impose that $\Delta > 0$. Thus, I end up looking for which values of $\kappa > 0$, Eq. (2) holds. However, Eq. (2) is a third order equation and not sure if analytically I can find the set of values of $\kappa > 0$ to satisfy Eq. (2).

Comment: Cubic equations always have analytical solutions.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire: I need to study the sign of $\Delta$ based on the solutions of the equation and make sure that $\kappa >0$ because clearly $\Delta$ is not always positive. Is there a way to explicitly find this region?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Trigonometric_solution_for_three_real_roots

Comment: @TheSimpliFire: thanks for the link. My understanding is that (i) these roots are when there is no quadratic term and (ii) these could be complex numbers, where I'm only looking for the real case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) to solve $
\Delta = \mu^2 - 4 c \kappa \left[ (b_2 + a \kappa) + (1+\kappa) (b_1 + a \kappa) \right] = 0$ for $\kappa$

```
solve([u^2 - 4*c*k*((b2+a*k) + (1+k)*(b1+a*k))],[k]);
```

$$k=\left(-{{\sqrt{3}\,i}\over{2}}-{{1}\over{2}}\right)\,\left({{
 \sqrt{27\,a^2\,u^4+\left(\left(72\,a\,{\it b_1}+144\,a^2\right)\,
 {\it b_2}-16\,{\it b_1}^3-24\,a\,{\it b_1}^2-48\,a^2\,{\it b_1}-128
 \,a^3\right)\,c\,u^2+\left(64\,a\,{\it b_2}^3+\left(-16\,{\it b_1}^2
 +128\,a\,{\it b_1}-64\,a^2\right)\,{\it b_2}^2+\left(-32\,{\it b_1}^
 3+64\,a\,{\it b_1}^2-128\,a^2\,{\it b_1}\right)\,{\it b_2}-16\,
 {\it b_1}^4-64\,a^2\,{\it b_1}^2\right)\,c^2}}\over{8\,3^{{{3}\over{
 2}}}\,a^2\,c}}-{{a^2\,\left(-27\,u^2-72\,{\it b_2}\,c+24\,{\it b_1}
 \,c\right)+a\,\left(12\,{\it b_1}^2\,c-36\,{\it b_1}\,{\it b_2}\,c
 \right)+8\,{\it b_1}^3\,c+64\,a^3\,c}\over{216\,a^3\,c}}\right)^{{{1
 }\over{3}}}+{{\left({{\sqrt{3}\,i}\over{2}}-{{1}\over{2}}\right)\,
 \left(a\,\left({\it b_1}-3\,{\it b_2}\right)+{\it b_1}^2+4\,a^2
 \right)}\over{9\,a^2\,\left({{\sqrt{27\,a^2\,u^4+\left(\left(72\,a\,
 {\it b_1}+144\,a^2\right)\,{\it b_2}-16\,{\it b_1}^3-24\,a\,
 {\it b_1}^2-48\,a^2\,{\it b_1}-128\,a^3\right)\,c\,u^2+\left(64\,a\,
 {\it b_2}^3+\left(-16\,{\it b_1}^2+128\,a\,{\it b_1}-64\,a^2\right)
 \,{\it b_2}^2+\left(-32\,{\it b_1}^3+64\,a\,{\it b_1}^2-128\,a^2\,
 {\it b_1}\right)\,{\it b_2}-16\,{\it b_1}^4-64\,a^2\,{\it b_1}^2
 \right)\,c^2}}\over{8\,3^{{{3}\over{2}}}\,a^2\,c}}-{{a^2\,\left(-27
 \,u^2-72\,{\it b_2}\,c+24\,{\it b_1}\,c\right)+a\,\left(12\,
 {\it b_1}^2\,c-36\,{\it b_1}\,{\it b_2}\,c\right)+8\,{\it b_1}^3\,c+
 64\,a^3\,c}\over{216\,a^3\,c}}\right)^{{{1}\over{3}}}}}-{{{\it b_1}+
 2\,a}\over{3\,a}}$$

$$k=\left({{\sqrt{3}\,i}\over{2}}-{{1}\over{2}}\right)\,\left({{
 \sqrt{27\,a^2\,u^4+\left(\left(72\,a\,{\it b_1}+144\,a^2\right)\,
 {\it b_2}-16\,{\it b_1}^3-24\,a\,{\it b_1}^2-48\,a^2\,{\it b_1}-128
 \,a^3\right)\,c\,u^2+\left(64\,a\,{\it b_2}^3+\left(-16\,{\it b_1}^2
 +128\,a\,{\it b_1}-64\,a^2\right)\,{\it b_2}^2+\left(-32\,{\it b_1}^
 3+64\,a\,{\it b_1}^2-128\,a^2\,{\it b_1}\right)\,{\it b_2}-16\,
 {\it b_1}^4-64\,a^2\,{\it b_1}^2\right)\,c^2}}\over{8\,3^{{{3}\over{
 2}}}\,a^2\,c}}-{{a^2\,\left(-27\,u^2-72\,{\it b_2}\,c+24\,{\it b_1}
 \,c\right)+a\,\left(12\,{\it b_1}^2\,c-36\,{\it b_1}\,{\it b_2}\,c
 \right)+8\,{\it b_1}^3\,c+64\,a^3\,c}\over{216\,a^3\,c}}\right)^{{{1
 }\over{3}}}+{{\left(-{{\sqrt{3}\,i}\over{2}}-{{1}\over{2}}\right)\,
 \left(a\,\left({\it b_1}-3\,{\it b_2}\right)+{\it b_1}^2+4\,a^2
 \right)}\over{9\,a^2\,\left({{\sqrt{27\,a^2\,u^4+\left(\left(72\,a\,
 {\it b_1}+144\,a^2\right)\,{\it b_2}-16\,{\it b_1}^3-24\,a\,
 {\it b_1}^2-48\,a^2\,{\it b_1}-128\,a^3\right)\,c\,u^2+\left(64\,a\,
 {\it b_2}^3+\left(-16\,{\it b_1}^2+128\,a\,{\it b_1}-64\,a^2\right)
 \,{\it b_2}^2+\left(-32\,{\it b_1}^3+64\,a\,{\it b_1}^2-128\,a^2\,
 {\it b_1}\right)\,{\it b_2}-16\,{\it b_1}^4-64\,a^2\,{\it b_1}^2
 \right)\,c^2}}\over{8\,3^{{{3}\over{2}}}\,a^2\,c}}-{{a^2\,\left(-27
 \,u^2-72\,{\it b_2}\,c+24\,{\it b_1}\,c\right)+a\,\left(12\,
 {\it b_1}^2\,c-36\,{\it b_1}\,{\it b_2}\,c\right)+8\,{\it b_1}^3\,c+
 64\,a^3\,c}\over{216\,a^3\,c}}\right)^{{{1}\over{3}}}}}-{{{\it b_1}+
 2\,a}\over{3\,a}}$$

$$k=\left({{\sqrt{27\,a^2\,u^4+\left(\left(72\,a\,{\it b_1}+144\,a^2
 \right)\,{\it b_2}-16\,{\it b_1}^3-24\,a\,{\it b_1}^2-48\,a^2\,
 {\it b_1}-128\,a^3\right)\,c\,u^2+\left(64\,a\,{\it b_2}^3+\left(-16
 \,{\it b_1}^2+128\,a\,{\it b_1}-64\,a^2\right)\,{\it b_2}^2+\left(-
 32\,{\it b_1}^3+64\,a\,{\it b_1}^2-128\,a^2\,{\it b_1}\right)\,
 {\it b_2}-16\,{\it b_1}^4-64\,a^2\,{\it b_1}^2\right)\,c^2}}\over{8
 \,3^{{{3}\over{2}}}\,a^2\,c}}-{{a^2\,\left(-27\,u^2-72\,{\it b_2}\,c
 +24\,{\it b_1}\,c\right)+a\,\left(12\,{\it b_1}^2\,c-36\,{\it b_1}\,
 {\it b_2}\,c\right)+8\,{\it b_1}^3\,c+64\,a^3\,c}\over{216\,a^3\,c}}
 \right)^{{{1}\over{3}}}+{{a\,\left({\it b_1}-3\,{\it b_2}\right)+
 {\it b_1}^2+4\,a^2}\over{9\,a^2\,\left({{\sqrt{27\,a^2\,u^4+\left(
 \left(72\,a\,{\it b_1}+144\,a^2\right)\,{\it b_2}-16\,{\it b_1}^3-24
 \,a\,{\it b_1}^2-48\,a^2\,{\it b_1}-128\,a^3\right)\,c\,u^2+\left(64
 \,a\,{\it b_2}^3+\left(-16\,{\it b_1}^2+128\,a\,{\it b_1}-64\,a^2
 \right)\,{\it b_2}^2+\left(-32\,{\it b_1}^3+64\,a\,{\it b_1}^2-128\,
 a^2\,{\it b_1}\right)\,{\it b_2}-16\,{\it b_1}^4-64\,a^2\,{\it b_1}^
 2\right)\,c^2}}\over{8\,3^{{{3}\over{2}}}\,a^2\,c}}-{{a^2\,\left(-27
 \,u^2-72\,{\it b_2}\,c+24\,{\it b_1}\,c\right)+a\,\left(12\,
 {\it b_1}^2\,c-36\,{\it b_1}\,{\it b_2}\,c\right)+8\,{\it b_1}^3\,c+
 64\,a^3\,c}\over{216\,a^3\,c}}\right)^{{{1}\over{3}}}}}-{{{\it b_1}+
 2\,a}\over{3\,a}}$$

You want the region of $\kappa > 0$ for $\Delta > 0$.

$\Delta$ is a  negative cubic in $\kappa$ of the form $\Delta = {\mu}^2 -(A\kappa^3 + B\kappa^2 + C\kappa)$ . $A,B,C \geq 0$.

Note that at $\kappa = 0$ , $\Delta = {\mu}^2$ , positive.

Note that for $\kappa > 0$ , -($A\kappa^3 + B\kappa^2 + C\kappa)$ is monotonic, always decreasing.

So there will only be one real zero when $\kappa > 0$

I think the third $k$ equation is the answer but I cannot prove this, the other two have a conjugate multiplier.